# Steps - code to display descriptives (mean, sd, etc.) for categorical data

Tags: r

I imported some data including race, education level, and an outcome variable as numbers. Changed the categorical vars to ordered factors. 
What can I do to describe these data? describe.by will not work for me but do not know if this is the correct function anyway. I want to view (hist) the outcome variable from the races independently, but also get the means, SDs, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few things. Whenever writing a post I strongly recommend writing out the code that you have tried and provide some fake data for others to help you with. Good questions will yield you stronger answers quicker. For example I would put some fake data like this:

```
fake_data <- data.frame(
    race = sample(c("A", "B"), 100, TRUE),
    edu = sample(c("None", "Some", "More"), 100, TRUE),
    value = rnorm(100, 50, 10)
)
```

And if you want to get some basic population statistics you could do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
fake_data %>% 
    group_by(race, edu) %>% 
    summarise(mu = mean(value),
                        sd = sd(value))
```

Then to get histograms you could do something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

fake_data %>% 
    ggplot(aes(value))+
    geom_histogram()+
    facet_wrap(~race)
```

However, without an example of the data or the desired output, I can only guess what you'd like.